# C program keeps crashing

Tags: c, crash

My program keeps crashing. The codes seems legit and correct. Wonder what's the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void queue(int length,int turns){
    int permutations,totalTurns;
    turns++;
    if (length>0){
        queue(length-1,turns);
        if (length>1){
            queue(length-2,turns);
        }
    } 
    else{
        permutations++;
        totalTurns+=turns;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    while(true){
        int length;
        float average;
        int permutations=0;
        int totalTurns=0;

        printf("Queue length: ");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        queue(length,-1);
        average=totalTurns/permutations;
        printf("The average turns are %f", average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post the error message you get when it crashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    int permutations=0;

    average=totalTurns/permutations;
```

You're dividing by zero.

Note that the `permutations` variable you've declared in `main()` is different from the one in `queue()`.

You should probably return the `permutations` value from `queue()`, like this:

```
int queue(int length,int turns){
    int permutations = 0;
    ...
    return permutations;
}

int main(void) {
    ...
    int permutations = queue(length,-1);
}
```

Comment: Oh! Then I should have just made a global variable instead. Thanks you your help ^^

Answer (score 2):

You should declare permutations as a global variable, i.e. outside main function as well as totalTurns because as others mentioned it's always 0 because even thought you declare it in function queue it's being forgotten outside it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int permutations=0;
static int totalTurns=0;


void queue(int length,int turns){
    turns++;
    if (length>0){
        queue(length-1,turns);
        if (length>1){
            queue(length-2,turns);
        }
    } 
    else{
        permutations++;
        totalTurns+=turns;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    while(true){
        int length;
        float average;
        int totalTurns=0;

        printf("Queue length: ");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        queue(length,-1);
        average=totalTurns/permutations;
        printf("The average turns are %f", average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neater just to return the value from `queue()` rather than messing around with globals.

Comment: Since both, `permutations` and `totalTurns` should be updated, one would need to return a struct, or an `int*`, or pass in a pointer to at least one of them. If you use globals, at least make them `static` so their scope is restricted to the compilation unit.